# Thread Freezes Loading Data via Backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, progress-bar, backgroundworker

The following code seems to freeze my thread when executing, which defeats the purpose of a progress which I'd like to add. Is there something I need to adjust to eliminate this? My assumption is that it has something to do with the shear amount of fields in the data I'm loading, in this particular example it's well over 150 fields (header row and 1 data row).

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Dim file As String = "<<file>>"
    Dim path As String = "<<path>>"

    Dim ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='<<source>>';Extended Properties='text';"
    Dim SQL = "SELECT * FROM  " & path & file

    tbl = New DataTable

    ' USING will close and dispose of resources
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
        cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, cn)

        cn.Open()
        Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(tbl)
        End Using

    End Using   ' close and dispose

    ' FIND the sequence column for this session
    For n = 0 To tbl.Columns.Count - 1
        If tbl.Columns(n).ColumnName.ToLowerInvariant = "sequence" Then
            SeqColIndex = n
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: 150 fields is not really that much.  There is nothing there to do anything with a progressbar though.

Comment: So if you don't suggest a progress bar, how do I eliminate the freeze factor?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. I have a simple progress bar to marquee prior to the `BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()`, then disable once the backgroundworker is complete. It probably freezes less than 5 secs.

Comment: I understand that, however a simple `ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee` does not zoom from 0 to 100 though.

Comment: So in the end, the freeze part is unavoidable?

Comment: Put aside the progress bar, when using the backgroundworker the UI freezes loading the data, same thing happens if I load the data without a backgroundworker.

Comment: Also, could be issue loading the data over the network, as opposed to a local file, just thought of that.

Comment: Just tested locally, same issue, freezes UI on loading.

Comment: Sorry, cannot duplicate. 250ms to open the connection and fill the table; 1500ms to iterate 200 columns **and** print the names to output. (250ms with no printing).  Move the code to a Button click and step thru it to see what it taking so long - 5 sec is insane, but 150 fields is not much.  Also set a breakpoint and be sure it is not called multiple times.  (and since that is basically my code, I was using the same as you)

Comment: Is there anywhere to see how long each step takes?

Comment: use a `Stopwatch` and look at `.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds`    http://pastebin.com/yT6sUB19

Comment: Note that if you ever run into a file with more than 255 columns this whole thing will fail. there is apparently a max of  255 fields it will read from a flat file.  I missed a NewLine in my test file so the data columns were appended to the header cols - it stopped reading at 255

Comment: Woah! I dont know why I was thinking I only had 150, but I have 242 fields, too close for comfort at the 255 max.